# How to add new ticket summary in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have create a ticket dashboard and it will shows two ticket summaries after I login with my administrator account. One is "Your ticket summary" and the other "All ticket summary". Right now I'm planning to let my administrator account to see other account's ticket summary (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1naE.png)), but I don't know how to add it on to the ticket dashboard can somebody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you asked the question as a comment in the previous post too! but anyway,

there are several approaches to do so. [Orchard Collaboration](http://orchardcollaboration.com) uses a widget to represents Ticket Summaries (both for the user and for the admin). The main logic is in the DashboardDriver at Modules/Orchard.CRM.Core/Drivers.

```
private DriverResult DisplayDetail(DashboardPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        if (this.services.WorkContext.CurrentUser == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var contentQuery = this.services.ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published);
        var statusRecords = this.basicDataService.GetStatusRecords().OrderBy(c => c.OrderId).ToList();

        DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();
        model.CurrentUserId = this.services.WorkContext.CurrentUser.Id;
        model.IsCustomer = this.crmContentOwnershipService.IsCurrentUserCustomer();
        model.IsOperator = this.services.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.OperatorPermission);
        dynamic state = new JObject();

        // Query items created by customer
        if (model.IsCustomer)
        {
            // Ticket contentType
            state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);

            state.RequestingUser_Id = model.CurrentUserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.RequestingUserType, state);

            var userTicketsCountByStateIds = groupQuery.GetCount(contentQuery, "TicketPartRecord", "StatusRecord.Id");

            model.CurrentUserRequestingTickets = new Collection<dynamic>();
            CRMHelper.AddStatusGroupRecordsToModel(statusRecords, userTicketsCountByStateIds, model.CurrentUserRequestingTickets);

            // overrude items of current users
            state.MaxDueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.TicketDueDateType, state);
            model.CurrentUserOverrudeRequestingTicketCount = contentQuery.Count();
        }

        // Query the counts of the current user tickets group by stateId
        // *******************************************************
        if (model.IsOperator)
        {
            // Ticket contentType
            state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);

            dynamic temp = new
            {
                Users = new int[] { model.CurrentUserId },
                Teams = new int[] { },
                BusinessUnits = new int[] { },
                AccessType = ContentItemPermissionAccessTypes.Assignee
            };

            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, ContentItemPermissionFilter.CategoryName, ContentItemPermissionFilter.AnySelectedUserTeamBusinessUnit, temp);

            var userTicketsCountByStateIds = groupQuery.GetCount(contentQuery, "TicketPartRecord", "StatusRecord.Id");

            model.CurrentUserTickets = new Collection<dynamic>();
            CRMHelper.AddStatusGroupRecordsToModel(statusRecords, userTicketsCountByStateIds, model.CurrentUserTickets);

            // overrude items of current users
            state.MaxDueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.TicketDueDateType, state);
            model.CurrentUserOverrudeItemsCount = contentQuery.Count();
            //*******************************************************
        }

        bool isAdmin = this.services.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.AdvancedOperatorPermission);

        if (isAdmin)
        {
            // Query the counts of the whole tickets in the system based on stateId
            state = new JObject();

            contentQuery = this.services.ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published);

            state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);
            var ticketCountsByStateIds = groupQuery.GetCount(contentQuery, "TicketPartRecord", "StatusRecord.Id");

            model.AllTickets = new Collection<dynamic>();
            CRMHelper.AddStatusGroupRecordsToModel(statusRecords, ticketCountsByStateIds, model.AllTickets);

            state.MaxDueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.TicketDueDateType, state);
            model.AllOverrudeItemsCount = contentQuery.Count();
        }

        // get items without any owner
        contentQuery = this.services.ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published);
        state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
        contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);
        contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, ContentItemPermissionFilter.CategoryName, "ContentItemPermissionPartRecord.ItemsWithoutAnyOwner", state);
        model.AllItemsWithoutOwnerCount = contentQuery.Count();

        // get overrude items count

        // display
        // 1) Number of your open, new, in progress, and closed tickets
        // 2) number of the unassigned, new, open, in progress and closed tickets in the system.
        return ContentShape("Parts_Dashboard",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Dashboard(
                Model: model
                ));
    }
```

You need to create a new Widget similar to that one. DashboardDriver represents tickets of the logined user as well as summary of all tickets. In the new widget, you can only represents summary tickets of the user. The new widget must have a UserId property and represents ticket summary of that user instead of the logined user. Something like this:

```
       private DriverResult DisplayDetail(NewUserDashboardPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        if (this.services.WorkContext.CurrentUser == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var contentQuery = this.services.ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published);
        var statusRecords = this.basicDataService.GetStatusRecords().OrderBy(c => c.OrderId).ToList();

        DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();
        model.CurrentUserId = NewUserDashboardPart.UserId;
        dynamic state = new JObject();

        // Query the counts of the current user tickets group by stateId
        // *******************************************************
             // Ticket contentType
            state.ContentTypes = "Ticket";
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, "Content", "ContentTypes", state);

            dynamic temp = new
            {
                Users = new int[] { model.CurrentUserId },
                Teams = new int[] { },
                BusinessUnits = new int[] { },
                AccessType = ContentItemPermissionAccessTypes.Assignee
            };

            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, ContentItemPermissionFilter.CategoryName, ContentItemPermissionFilter.AnySelectedUserTeamBusinessUnit, temp);

            var userTicketsCountByStateIds = groupQuery.GetCount(contentQuery, "TicketPartRecord", "StatusRecord.Id");

            model.CurrentUserTickets = new Collection<dynamic>();
            CRMHelper.AddStatusGroupRecordsToModel(statusRecords, userTicketsCountByStateIds, model.CurrentUserTickets);

            // overrude items of current users
            state.MaxDueDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            contentQuery = this.projectionManagerWithDynamicSort.ApplyFilter(contentQuery, TicketFieldsFilter.CategoryName, TicketFieldsFilter.TicketDueDateType, state);
            model.CurrentUserOverrudeItemsCount = contentQuery.Count();
            //*******************************************************

        // display
        // 1) Number of your open, new, in progress, and closed tickets
        // 2) number of the unassigned, new, open, in progress and closed tickets in the system.
        return ContentShape("Parts_Dashboard",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Dashboard(
                Model: model
                ));
    }
```